# SQL query to retrieve taxonomy of product in Woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I have many products in about 8 different categories.  When users purchase items, the email that is sent to them lists the products in the order that they added them to their cart which appears very chaotic.  I would like to order the products instead by product category, and have the products be listed alphabetically within each category.  I think this "double-sort" functionality is best accomplished by modifying the SQL query which is called just before sending the email, which is like so :

```
$line_items = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
SELECT      order_item_id, order_item_name, order_item_type
FROM        {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items
WHERE       order_id = %d
AND         order_item_type IN ( '" . implode( "','", $type ) . "' )
ORDER BY    order_item_id
//Would like this to be ORDER BY 'product category', 'product name' ASC//
", $this->id ) );
```

What I can't figure out is how to retrieve the product category in this query.  I know it requires a JOIN, but for the life of me I can't trace the key relationships in the database tables.

Update: a woocommerce product is stored as a post with regular WordPress taxonomy, so if someone knows how to retrieve the category of a post in WordPress I think that'll work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code, but this is only useful when each of your product belongs to only one category

```
$line_items = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
SELECT      DISTINCT woi.order_item_id, woi.order_item_name, woi.order_item_type, woim.meta_value AS product_id, t.name AS product_category
FROM        {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi
LEFT JOIN   {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woim 
ON ( woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id AND woim.meta_key LIKE '_product_id' )
LEFT JOIN   {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships AS tr
ON ( tr.object_id = woim.meta_value )
LEFT JOIN   {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy AS tt ON ( tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id )
LEFT JOIN   {$wpdb->prefix}terms AS t ON ( t.term_id = tt.term_id )
WHERE       woi.order_id = %d
AND         woi.order_item_type IN ( '" . implode( "','", $type ) . "' )
AND         tt.taxonomy LIKE 'product_cat'
ORDER BY    product_category, woi.order_item_name
", $this->id ) );
```

Hope this will be useful.